# ASP.NET Core MVC: create an empty List<> of a class model

Tags: c#, list, asp.net-core-mvc

I am creating an ASP.NET Core MVC app.

I have a class entity like this:

```
 public class NewModel
 {
        public string? FirstName { get; set; }  
        public string? LastName { get; set; }  
        public string? MiddleInitial { get; set; }
}
```

I need to create a `List<NewModel>` of 10 or 20 empty elements.

I wrote this code and it works:

```
List<NewModel> _new = new();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
     NewModel dependents = new();
     _new.Add(dependents);
}
```

Is there a neater way to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use NBuilder

first you Install-Package NBuilder of nuget

then you can use this is code

```
var _builder = new Builder(new BuilderSettings { AutoNameProperties = false });

List<NewModel> list = _builder.CreateListOfSize<NewModel>(10).Build().ToList();
```